# How can I query data from one table by using multiple conditions and by looking for a value in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three ORACLE SQL tables where I have to query **DATA_TABLE** and pull **dataid**'s whose **attr** is 2000 and value is cat and also the **value** for **attr** = 2001 has to be available in NAME_TABLE **oldname** column and I have to display **Name** from **DOC_TABLE**(using **dataid's** we got from above) and Code from **Name_Table**

[image: Tables with Sample data]

From the above table my output has to be

**Name**,**Code**

FirstName, DG

Because dataid 1 in DATA_TABLE for attr 2000 its value is Cat and for attr 2001 its value is dog which is available in NAME_TABLE oldname column, As Name where dataid=1 in DOC_TABLE is FirstName and code for dog in NAME_TABLE is DG

Comment: Please post sample data as text not images.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase your query as follows:

```
select do.name, na.code

-- start the join here
from doc_table do

-- pull dataid's from DATA_TABLE whose attr is 2000 and value is cat
inner join data_table da on da.dataid = do.dataid and da.attr = 2000 and da.value = 'cat'

-- pull code from NAME_TABLE
inner join name_table na on na.oldname = da.value

-- the value for attr = 2001 has to be available in NAME_TABLE
where exists(
    select 1
    from data_table da1
    inner join name_table na1 on na1.oldname = da1.value
    where da1.dataid = do.dataid and da1.attr = 2001
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `analytical function` as following:

```
Select distinct name, code from
(select do.name, na.code,
Count(case when da.value='cat' and da.attr=2000 then 1 end) 
Over (Partition by do.dataid) as cat_cnt,
Count(case when na.code is not null and da.attr=2001 then 1 end) 
Over (Partition by do.dataid) as code_cnt
from doc_table do
Left join data_table da on da.dataid = do.dataid
Left join name_table na on na.oldname = da.value)
Where cat_cnt > 0 and code_count > 0;
```

Cheers!!